# Pyzbar doesn't recognize qrcode, but works with barcodes

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, zbar

I'm working on an Android app. It's a QRCodeScanner, with Kivy and python. The code works fine on windows, but when I compile to Android, it doesn't recognize QRCodes, but it recognize only Barcodes.
Here is my code

```
label = Label(text="", halign='left', valign='bottom', size_hint=(.5,.2))
x = Camera(play=True, index=0)
class MyCamera(App):
    def build(self):
        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols = 1
        Window.size = (360, 640)
        self.window.add_widget(x)
        self.window.add_widget(label)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 33.0)
        return self.window
    def update(self, dt):
        texture = x.texture
        size = texture.size
        pixels = texture.pixels
        pil_image = Image.frombytes(mode="RGBA", size=size, data=pixels)
        numpypicture = numpy.array(pil_image)
        decoded = pyzbar.pyzbar.decode(numpypicture)
        label.text = str(decoded)
        if len(str(decoded)) > 2:
            # do something
```

I also tried to use cv2, but it crashes at startup for something like "not compatible with android"

Buildozer.spec file

```
requirements =python3,kivy,pyzbar,Pillow,numpy

fullscreen = 1

android.permissions = INTERNET,CAMERA
```

this is all what I changed

Also, the camera is rotated by 90° on Android, but on windows works fine

Have you got any idea to solve?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70895762/pyzbar-on-android-doesnt-read-qrcodes-but-reads-barcodes/70954786#70954786). I too needed to rotate by 90º and you are probably missing that the image is being mirrored. I hope it fixes your problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).